# VBA to open Sharepoint folder in Windows Explorer, not Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a button in MS Access to open a Sharepoint folder in Windows Explorer, not Internet Explorer. I had it working momentarily, and don't know what broke. This currently opens the sharepoint folder in Internet Explorer.

```
Dim Foldername As String
Foldername = "http://vaww.visn21.portal.va.gov/sanfrancisco/education/EDADMIN/Service Timekeeping Records\"
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Edit: I have also tried this code, same effect where it opens it in internet explorer, not windows explorer.

```
Dim path As String
path = "http://vaww.visn21.portal.va.gov/sanfrancisco/education/EDADMIN/Service Timekeeping Records\"
Shell "cmd /C start """" /max """ & path & """", vbHide
End Sub
```

Edit 2 : Tried this code, still just opens internet explorer instead of windows explorer

```
Call Shell("explorer """"" & "http://vaww.visn21.portal.va.gov/sanfrancisco/education/EDADMIN/Service Timekeeping Records\" & """""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Ideally this will be used as the primary interface to access these folders once their names are changed to program numbers instead of program names (And thus the links won't break every time a program name changes).

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know WHY this works, I think it has something to do with the difference between forward slashes and backslashes, but here's the code that wound up working. This code checks to see if a particular folder exists, creates the folder if it does not, and then tries to open the folder in Windows Explorer, not internet explorer.

```
Private Sub ButtonMkDirTest_Click()
myWorkBookBasePath = "\\vaww.visn21.portal.va.gov\sanfrancisco\education\EDADMIN\TESTFOLDER"

If Len(Dir(myWorkBookBasePath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir myWorkBookBasePath
End If
Dim path As String
path = myWorkBookBasePath
Shell "cmd /C start """" /max """ & path & """", vbHide
End Sub
```

Comment: As mentioned in my formal answer, this behaviour is the result of your NOT specifying ''http://'' as the protocol for handling the command. If you had included http:// in the variable 'my WorkBookBasePath' then the http protocol would have invoked Internet Explorer (if that is the default browser set on your Windows system).

Answer (score 0):

**Watch out for that http protocol, it'll kill you every time!**

No one else seems interested in this topic, probably for the best of reasons. You have to be - politely put - ***eccentric*** to try to open an *internet* address with a local disk utility.

Windows Explorer is designed to open local folders only. Windows is designed around a series of *protocols*, principally the **http:** protocol, but also the **file:** protocol. There are others, but for the current topic those are the important two.

The **http:** protocol is designed to open *Internet* Explorer, and the **file:** protocol is designed to open *Windows* Explorer. There are a whole bunch of Registry keys which control this behaviour.

In the current question, the poster has specified **http:** as part of the target address, in the case which resulted in Internet Explorer opening. That occurred even though Internet Explorer was not specified on the command line, because when Windows encounters a **http:** address, the Registry is set up to cause Internet Explorer to run.

In the second case, where the o/p was puzzled by Windows Explorer opening, if you look closely at his second command you'll notice that this 2nd command does not expressly mention **http:** in the command, which was why the **http:** protocol did not take over the handling of the command (so Internet Explorer was not called).